# Can I skip my first flight and get on the second flight?

Tags: air-travel, transit

I've booked a ticket to Tokyo with Alitalia from Amsterdam. I have one stop at Milan Linate (LIN) and the next flight will leave from Milan Malpensa (MXP). I have 3.15 hours to get to Malpensa Airport. I find this not enough time, so I booked another ticket to Milan a day earlier with Iberia.

Is it possible to skip the first flight on Alitalia to Milan Linate and get on the flight from Milan Malpensa to Tokyo?

Comment: No.  But it will not matter.  If AMS-LIN is delayed, AZ is responsible for reaccommodating you.  Basically, you've probably lost the IB ticket.

Answer (score 1):

Usually not. As soon as you miss the first flight, the rest of your itinerary is cancelled.

You should probably contact Alitalia and try to change your itinerary to just be MXP-Tokyo.

Answer (score 0):

No. They will cancel your second flight if you don't take the first leg. Google "Hidden City ticketing" for more details.

However, if you have a single ticket, than Alitalia has full responsibility to ge your to your destination. If you miss your connection, they will rebook you for free and possibly put you up in a hotel for the night. The shuttle from Linate to Malpenza takes between and 1 and 1.5 hours (depending on time of day) so it doesn't seem impossible. Does your ticket include the shuttle ride? I would also assume that Alitalia checks your bags through, so they would have to get those to Malpenza as well. If you are worried about the connection time, contact Alitalia and talk it through with them. The may be able to rebook you an on earlier flight for free.

Comment: i called Alitalia they said it is my own responsibility to get to the airport and be on time

Comment: @Apotacyll. They sold you a single ticket that involves an airport change from Linate to Malpenza and they said it's your own responsibility to arrange for that transfer? That sounds highly unusual.

Comment: Yeah they said that. I paid €130 to rebook my flight to rome instead of milan so now i can catch my flight